# Behavior of Inner depends on List dimensions?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following case:

```
list1 = {q, r, s};
list2 = {{a, 2}, {b, 3}, {c, 1, f}};
Inner[{#1, #2} &, list1, list2, List]
(* Out[] := {{q, {a, 2}}, {r, {b, 3}}, {s, {c, 1, f}}} *)
```

However, if the last element of `list2` has `Length` 2:

```
list1 = {q, r, s};
list2 = {{a, 2}, {b, 3}, {c, 1}};
Inner[{#1, #2} &, list1, list2, List]
(* Out[] := {{{q, a}, {r, b}, {s, c}}, {{q, 2}, {r, 3}, {s, 1}}} *)
```

I would have expected (and wanted) a result like:

```
(* Out[] := {{q, {a, 2}}, {r, {b, 3}}, {s, {c, 1}}} *)
```

So,

1. Why does this `Inner` operation change if the `list2` entries are all of the same length?
2. How can I generate an output like the expected result?

---

**Edit** I came up with a potential answer to question 2:

```
Partition[Riffle[list1, list2], 2]
Out[] := {{q, {a, 2}}, {r, {b, 3}}, {s, {c, 1}}}
```

but this seems somehow too-complicated.

Comment: `Inner[]` in your second case is just being consistent with the behavior of `Dot[]`; contrast with `{q, r, s}.{{a, 2}, {b, 3}, {c, 1}}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Inner` is a generalization of `Dot`, and `Dot` has specific behavior for vectors, matrices and tensors:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{a, b, c} . {x[1, 2], x[3, 4], x[5, 6]}

{a, b, c} . {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
```

> ```
> a x[1, 2] + b x[3, 4] + c x[5, 6]
>
> {a + 3 b + 5 c, 2 a + 4 b + 6 c}
> ```

When `Inner` detects a complete tensor it changes behavior in a similar fashion.
Likewise the second and third arguments of `Inner` are order-dependent like the arguments of `Dot`.

Just as `x` was used in `Dot` above, one can use an arbitrary head to "shield" the tensor depth from `Inner`.  `Unevaluated` is a nice choice in this case because it will be automatically stripped by `&`.

```
list1 = {q, r, s};
list2 = {{a, 2}, {b, 3}, {c, 1}};

Inner[{#1, #2} &, list1, Unevaluated /@ list2, List]
```

> ```
> {{q, {a, 2}}, {r, {b, 3}}, {s, {c, 1}}}
> ```

Another option would be:

```
Inner[{#, #2[[1]]} &, list1, "" /@ list2, List]
```

---

As already mentioned by J. M., for #2:

```
{list1, list2}\[Transpose]
```

> ```
> {{q, {a, 2}}, {r, {b, 3}}, {s, {c, 1}}}
> ```

Comment: +1. It's probably a good idea to use `MapAt` with `Unevaluated` since you only need one modification for it to stop being a full array

Comment: @Rojo that could work but `Unevaluated` is not a general solution (for example with `List` in place of `{#1, #2} &` which does not evaluate) so I think the second method may be more appropriate, and doing that for only one element would complicate things. (thanks for the vote.)

Comment: I see your point. Perhaps this as ugly as it is could be more general `Inner[List, list1, #, List] &[
 MapAt[Sequence, Unevaluated[#] &[list2], {1, 1}]]`. More general is still not general. It wouldn't work with `HoldComplete` instead of the first `List`

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a better answer to the second part of my question:

```
Thread[{list1, list2}]
(* Out[] := {{q, {a, 2}}, {r, {b, 3}}, {s, {c, 1}}} *)
```

which works equally well if the entries in the lists are of different lengths.

Comment: I'd use `Transpose[{list1, list2}]` myself.