# Map a function across a list conditionally

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, map

It seems that this is a really basic question, and I feel that the answer should be obvious to me. However, I am not seeing. Can you please help me? Thanks.

Suppose I have a list of data `list` and a selector list `sel`.  I would like to `Map` some function `f` onto elements in `list` that correspond to `True` in the selector list `sel`.

Thus for the input

```
list = {1, 10, 100};
sel = {True, False, True};
```

I would like to obtain the output

```
{f[1], 10, f[100]}
```

I can think of some complicated ways to accomplish this (e.g., using `Table` to step through both `list` and `sel` using an iterator `i`; or find the positions of `True` in `sel` using `Position` and then `MapAt` at those positions), but not simple ways. Do you have any advice?

Comment: what's wrong with `MapAt[f, list, Position[sel, True]]` ?

Comment: I like this question as it asks about something that isn't necessarily straightforward, but there are copious ways of accomplishing it. So, +1.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi that is true, and that is why [Mr.W's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9797/52) is so important: deciding on which one. Arguably, I weigh this against readability and maintainability. If it is not readable/maintainable, then it had better be very, very fast, or speed must be absolutely necessary. Otherwise, I go for something I can understand easily 6mos later.

Comment: @rcollyer: put another way, "I don't want to have to think so hard when reading code I've written many moons ago."

Comment: @J.M. of course, there are some code fragments of mine that I have difficulty understanding the next day despite the fact that they work. Modifying them is nightmarish. It is one of the principal reasons I've moved away from using postfix form, and instead tend to write small easily composable functions. Although, postfix creeps in now and again, but it isn't my primary vehicle for running successive transformations anymore.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

***Updated with new functions and additional timings***

Since this question inspired so many answers, I think there is a need to compare them.
I have included two of my own functions, freely borrowing from previous answers:

```
wizard1[] :=
 Inner[Compose, sel /. {True -> f, False -> Identity}, list, List]

wizard2[] :=
 Module[{x = list}, x[[#]] = f /@ x[[#]]; x] & @ 
  SparseArray[sel, Automatic, False]@"AdjacencyLists"
```

(`wizard1` may not work as expected if `list` [is a matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9235/121); a workaround is shown in that post.)

**Notes**

These timings are conducted with *Mathematica* 7 on Windows 7 and may differ significantly from those conducted on other platforms and versions.

Specifically, I know this affects Leonid's method, as `Pick` has been improved between versions 7 and 8.  His newer form with `` Developer`ToPackedArray@Boole `` is slower on my system, so I used the original.

Rojo's first function had to be modified or it fails on packed arrays, but I believe this affects other versions as well.

kguler's method `list /. Dispatch[Thread[# -> f1 /@ #] &@Pick[list, sel]]` does not produce the correct result if there are duplicates in `list` and was omitted from the timings.

### Timings with symbolic (undefined) `f`

Here are timings for all functions, when `f` is undefined:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

$x$ is length of `list`; $y$ is average time in seconds.

We can see that all the methods appear to have the same time complexity with the exception of one, the line at the top on the right-hand side.  This is `MapAt[f, list, Position[sel, True]]` at it makes quite clear "what's wrong with" this method.  The warning on [this page](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_11.html) regarding `MapAt` rings true.

Timings for **10^5** in the chart by rank are:

$\begin{array}{rl}
 \text{wizard2} & 0.02248 \\
 \text{ecoxlinux2} & 0.02996 \\
 \text{wizard1} & 0.03184 \\
 \text{leonid} & 0.03244 \\
 \text{simon} & 0.03868 \\
 \text{ruebenko} & 0.04116 \\
 \text{artes3} & 0.0468 \\
 \text{rojo3} & 0.04928 \\
 \text{verbeia} & 0.05744 \\
 \text{rm2} & 0.0656 \\
 \text{rm1} & 0.0936 \\
 \text{artes2} & 0.0936 \\
 \text{artes1} & 0.0966 \\
 \text{jm2} & 0.106 \\
 \text{rojo2} & 0.1154 \\
 \text{rojo4} & 0.1404 \\
 \text{kguler4} & 0.1434 \\
 \text{kguler2} & 0.1496 \\
 \text{kguler1} & 0.1592 \\
 \text{jm1} & 0.1654 \\
 \text{rojo1} & 0.3432 \\
 \text{ecoxlinux1} & 19.797
\end{array}$

### Timings with a numeric compilable `f`

For an array of **10^6** Reals and with `` f = 1.618` + # & `` timings are:

$\begin{array}{rl}
 \text{wizard2} & 0.04864 \\
 \text{leonid} & 0.2154 \\
 \text{ecoxlinux2} & 0.452 \\
 \text{ruebenko} & 0.53 \\
 \text{artes3} & 0.577 \\
 \text{simon} & 0.639 \\
 \text{wizard1} & 0.702 \\
 \text{rojo3} & 0.811 \\
 \text{rm1} & 0.982 \\
 \text{verbeia} & 1.014 \\
 \text{artes2} & 1.06 \\
 \text{artes1} & 1.123 \\
 \text{rojo2} & 1.279 \\
 \text{rm2} & 1.357 \\
 \text{jm2} & 1.45 \\
 \text{rojo4} & 1.747 \\
 \text{kguler4} & 1.841 \\
 \text{kguler2} & 1.934 \\
 \text{kguler1} & 2.012 \\
 \text{jm1} & 2.106 \\
 \text{rojo1} & 3.37
\end{array}$

**We're not done yet.**

Leonid wrote his method specifically to allow for auto-compilation within `Map`, and my second method is directly based on his.  We can take this a step further for a `Listable` function or one constructed of such functions as is `` f = 1.618` + # & `` by using `f @` in place of `f /@` as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7925/121):

```
Module[{x = list}, x[[#]] = f @ x[[#]]; x] & @ 
  SparseArray[sel, Automatic, False]@"AdjacencyLists" // timeAvg
```

> 0.03496

---

### Reference

The functions, as I named and used them, are:

```
ruebenko[] :=
 Block[{f},
  f[i_, True] := f[i];
  f[i_, False] := i;
  MapThread[f, {list, sel}]
 ]

artes1[] :=
 (If[#1[[2]], f[#1[[1]]], #1[[1]]] &) /@ Transpose[{list, sel}]

artes2[] :=
 If[Last@#, f@First@#, First@#] & /@ Transpose[{list, sel}]

artes3[] :=
 Inner[If[#2, f, Identity][#] &, list, sel, List]

ecoxlinux1[] :=
 MapAt[f, list, Position[sel, True]]

ecoxlinux2[] :=
 Transpose[{list, sel}] /. {{x_, True} :> f[x], {x_, _} :> x}

rm1[] :=
 Transpose[{list, sel}] /. {x_, y_} :> (f^Boole[y])[x] /. 1[x_] :> x

rm2[] :=
 Transpose[{list, sel}] /. {x_, y_} :> (y /. {True -> f, False -> Identity})[x]

rojo1[] :=
 With[{list = Developer`FromPackedArray@list},
  Normal[SparseArray[{i_ /; sel[[i]] :> f[list[[i]]], i_ :> list[[i]]}, Dimensions[list]]]
 ]

rojo2[] :=
 Total[{#~BitXor~1, #} &@Boole@sel {list, f /@ list}]

rojo3[] :=
 If[#1, f[#2], #2] & ~MapThread~ {sel, list}

rojo4[] :=
 #2 /. _ /; #1 :> f[#2] & ~MapThread~ {sel, list}

jm1[] :=
 MapIndexed[If[sel[[Sequence @@ #2]], f[#1], #1] &, list]

jm2[] :=
 MapIndexed[If[Extract[sel, #2], f[#1], #1] &, list]

verbeia[] :=
 If[#2, f[#1], #1] & @@@ Transpose[{list, sel}]

kguler1[] :=
 MapThread[(#2 f[#1] + (1 - #2) #1) &, {list, Boole[#] & /@ sel}]

kguler2[] :=
 (#2 f[#1] + (1 - #2) #1) & @@@ Thread[{list, Boole@sel}]

(*kguler3[]:=
list/.Dispatch@Thread[#->f/@#]&@Pick[list,sel]*)

kguler4[] :=
  Inner[(#2 f[#1] + (1 - #2) #1) &, list, Boole@sel, List]

simon[] :=
 Block[{g},
  g[True, x_] := f[x];
  g[False, x_] := x;
  SetAttributes[g, Listable];
  g[sel, list]
 ]

leonid[] :=
  With[{pos = Pick[Range@Length@list, sel]},
   Module[{list1 = list},
    list1[[pos]] = f /@ list1[[pos]];
    list1
   ]
  ]

wizard1[] :=
 Inner[Compose, sel /. {True -> f, False -> Identity}, list, List]

wizard2[] :=
 Module[{x = list}, x[[#]] = f /@ x[[#]]; x] & @ 
  SparseArray[sel, Automatic, False]@"AdjacencyLists"
```

Timing code:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := 
  Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

funcs = {ruebenko, artes1, artes2, artes3,(*ecoxlinux1,*)ecoxlinux2, 
   rm1, rm2, rojo1, rojo2, rojo3, rojo4, jm1, jm2, verbeia, kguler1, 
   kguler2,(*kguler3,*)kguler4, simon, leonid, wizard1, wizard2};

ClearAll[f]
time1 = Table[
  list = RandomInteger[99, n];
  sel = RandomChoice[{True, False}, n];
  timeAvg@ fn[],
  {fn, funcs},
  {n, 10^Range@5}
 ] ~Monitor~ fn

f = 1.618 + # &;
time2long = Table[
    list = RandomReal[99, 1*^6];
    sel = RandomChoice[{True, False}, 1*^6];
    {fn, timeAvg@ fn[]},
    {fn, funcs}
   ] ~Monitor~ fn
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if the speed difference between `Map` (`/@`) and `Apply` at level 1 (`@@@`) is general?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nice work ! You haven't mentioned `artes3[]:=Inner[If[#2, f, Identity][#1] &, list, sel, List]` which seems faster than `artes2`.

Comment: @Rojo I'm not sure if these timings are reliable enough but I found `rojo3[]` is the fastes of yours but `artes3[]` was even slightly faster.

Comment: @Artes (et al) as stated this is a first pass for timings and not conclusive.  Further, this test was performed on *Mathematica* 7 and may not agree with later versions.  I already see several errors in my method that I shall correct tomorrow.  For now I believe the ranking is mostly right.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, this seems to be another one of those cases when something has a bug for PackedArrays. :S

Comment: Nice. This does answer my question.

Comment: rojo1 is second to last if you unpack the RandomInteger first, and artes3 comes between rojo3 and verbeia

Comment: That graph might as well not be there...

Comment: @R.M Why?  I think it shows that the rankings are quite consistent.

Comment: +1 for beating all with a solution that uses a function that's supposedly been superseded in 1991

Comment: How did you get to know of AdjacencyLists?

Comment: +1, but in your last method, you should know explicitly that your function is Listable. This is why I discarded it (of course, I tried that as well, and actually my timings (V8) did not reveal any difference).

Comment: @Rojo Thanks! :-D I learned that from [Oliver Ruebenkoenig on MathGroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Jan/msg00792.html).  You can get the full list of valid "properties" with `SparseArray[{1}]["Properties"]` these allow you to access all the internal parts of a `SparseArray` object by name, which will presumably be more robust than by `Part` which might change in later versions.

Comment: @Leonid yes, which is why I only mentioned it in a footnote on optimization.  Interesting that perhaps in v8 it making that optimization automatically.

Answer (score 20):

Perhaps something like this:

```
list = {1, 10, 100};
sel = {True, False, True};
MapThread[f, {list, sel}]
(* {f[1, True], f[10, False], f[100, True]} *)
```

So, like:

```
f[i_, True] := f[i]
f[i_, False] := i

MapThread[f, {list, sel}]
(* {f[1], 10, f[100]} *)
```

Answer (score 16):

```
If[ #[[2]], f[#[[1]]], #[[1]]] & /@ Transpose[{list, sel}]
```

> ```
> {f[1], 10, f[100]}
> ```

this should be a bit faster :

```
If[ Last @ #, f @ First @ #, First @ #] & /@ Transpose[{list, sel}]
```

or using `Inner` :

```
Inner[ If[#2, f, Identity][#1] &, list, sel, List]
```

Answer (score 15):

This version seems to be about twice faster than the fastest so far (generally, as much faster as small is a fraction of selected elements), and about an order of magintude faster when Listable functions are mapped on a numerical list - since it automatically utilizes `Map` auto-compilation in such cases:

```
ClearAll[conditionalMap];
conditionalMap[f_, lst_, condlst_] :=
  With[{pos = Pick[Range[Length[lst]], Developer`ToPackedArray@Boole[condlst], 1]},
    Module[{list1 = lst},
      list1[[pos]] = f /@ list1[[pos]];
      list1]];
```

Comment: You would think that that would result in going over the list multiple times and cause it to be much slower, but `Pick` combined with the vector form of `Equals` is such a powerful combination, and thoroughly underutilized. Unfortunately, `Pick` does not usually occur to me to use, +1.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for the upvote. Actually, this was first thing that came to my mind given effciency considerations, and the desire to utilize autocompilation of `Map` automatically.

Comment: While this is a nice answer, a comment on `Pick` is that is unpacks.

Comment: @ruebenko I thought it no longer did in version 8?

Comment: Grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrreat

Comment: @ruebenko Good point, please see an updated version (which does not unpack unless the mapped function itself is symbolic and demands it).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, in a way there were two 'issues' one Leonid fixed and this one is not an issue any longer unpack ``Developer`PackedArrayQ@Pick[Range[5], RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 5], 1]`` - but this one still does ``Developer`PackedArrayQ@Pick[Range[5], RandomChoice[{True, False}, 5]]``

Comment: @ruebenko I would say that the issue I did not fix is really a flaw of the original formulation of the problem, which would be better off by using `1` and `0` in place of `True` and `False` to select elements, if one wants to incorporate numeric functions / lists as well.

Answer (score 13):

How about something unconventional?

```
Transpose[{list, sel}] /. {x_, y_} :> (f^Boole[y])[x] /. 1[x_] :> x
(* {f[1], 10, f[100]} *)
```

Again, another unconventional solution:

```
Transpose[{list, sel}] /. {x_, y_} :> (y /. {True -> f, False -> Identity})[x]
```

Comment: +1, this one gives room for unconventional solutions

Comment: @Rojo Added one more :)

Comment: Can't +1 again but would... I suspect more unconventionals to come. Think something with `Composition@@list`

Comment: Alternatively: `Transpose[{list, sel}] /. {x_, y_} :> Operate[If[# === 1, Identity, #] &, (f^Boole[y])[x]]`

Comment: @J.M. I considered `Operate`, but didn't think it was as neat. Also, if you're using an `If` statement, then might as well write `If[#2, f, Identity][#1] & @@@ Transpose[{list, sel}]` or as in Verbeia's answer

Answer (score 10):

Here is another way:

```
Transpose[{list, sel}] /. {{x_, True} :> f[x], {x_, _} :> x}
```

Although I think that `MapAt` with `Position` seems the cleanest way.

Comment: I don't think `MapAt` is cleaner than this. But I would use `Transpose` instead of `Thread` +1

Comment: @Rojo, Thanks. I guess it is in the eye of the beholder. Updated to use `Transpose`.

Comment: Yes, it's a matter of taste. I like it more because it is faster, an can be put as a small `\[Transpose]`. And because I like algebra stuff

Comment: @Rojo, Oh, I agree with your `Transpose` comment. I was referring to `MapAt` versus this. :)

Answer (score 10):

Just playing around

```
Normal@SparseArray[{i_ /; sel[[i]] :> f[list[[i]]], i_ :> list[[i]]}, Dimensions@list]
```

Another playful one

```
Total[{#~BitXor~1, #} &@Boole@sel {list, f /@ list}]
```

An almost similar solution to @Artes and @ruebenko's that I find neater could be

```
If[#1, f[#2], #2] & ~ MapThread ~ {sel, list}
```

The function on the lhs of `MapThread` could be written as `#2 /. _ /; #1 :> f[#2] &`,

or as

```
Function[sel, 
     If[sel, f, 
      RandomChoice[{Identity, 
        Evaluate, # &}]]][#1]@#2 &~MapThread~{sel, list}
```

Answer (score 9):

Another one, similar to ruebenko's but a bit faster on my machine:

```
simon[] := Block[{g},
  g[True, x_] := f[x];
  g[False, x_] := x;
  SetAttributes[g, Listable];
  g[sel, list]]
```

Answer (score 8):

I quite like the following myself:

```
list = {1, 10, 100}; sel = {True, False, True};

MapIndexed[If[sel[[Sequence @@ #2]], f[#1], #1] &, list]
    {f[1], 10, f[100]}
```

Here, we leverage the fact that `MapIndexed[]` conveniently produces the position of the objects its first argument is being mapped at. For the positions to be usable by `Part[]`, one has to turn the `List[]` of positions into a `Sequence[]` that can be spliced into `Part[]`. Otherwise, here is an alternative:

```
MapIndexed[If[Extract[sel, #2], f[#1], #1] &, list]
```

As mentioned in the docs, "`Extract[expr, {i, j, …}]` is equivalent to `Part[expr, i, j, …]`."

---

To demonstrate the flexibility of this approach, here's how to adapt it if `list` and `sel` are **matrices** as opposed to one-dimensional lists:

```
list = {{2, 1, 1, -3}, {-8, -1, 0, 2}, {-4, 4, -8, -6}, {-8, -1, 9, -2}};
sel = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> True, {4, _} -> True}, {4, 4}, False];

MapIndexed[If[Extract[sel, #2], f[#1], #1] &, list, {ArrayDepth[list]}]
    {{f[2], 1, 1, -3}, {-8, f[-1], 0, 2}, {-4, 4, f[-8], -6}, {f[-8], f[-1], f[9], f[-2]}}
```

The `ArrayDepth[]` ensures that `f[]` is only applied to the innermost elements of the given matrices; the same behavior will be seen if instead of matrices, you have rank-$n$ tensors.

---

Here's a generalization of the snippets given above, encapsulated as a routine blending both the qualities of `Map[]` and `Pick[]`:

```
MapPick[fun_, list_, sel_, patt_, lev_] := 
  MapIndexed[If[MatchQ[Extract[sel, #2], patt], fun[#1], #1] &, list, lev] /;
  Dimensions[list] === Dimensions[sel]

MapPick[fun_, list_, sel_, patt_: True] := MapPick[fun, list, sel, patt, {ArrayDepth[list]}]
```

Answer (score 7):

For those that don't like the look of multiple nested brackets arising from the use of `Part` (eg `[[1]]`), I would point out that Artes' answer is equivalent to using `Apply` at level 1, which has the shorthand syntax `@@@`

```
If[#2, f[#1], #1] & @@@ Transpose[{list, sel}]
```

Comment: and for those that don't like `[]` arising from a function call, we have `If @@ {#2, f@#1, #1} & @@@ Transpose@{list, sel}` :D :P (although, it doesn't respect `If`'s attributes)

Answer (score 7):

```
 MapThread[(#2 f1[#1] + (1 - #2) #1) &, {list, Boole@ sel}]
```

or

```
(#2 f1[#1] + (1 - #2) #1) & @@@ Thread[{list, Boole@sel}]
```

or

```
Inner[(#2 f1[#1] + (1 - #2) #1) &, list, Boole@sel, List]
```

or

```
 list /. Dispatch[Thread[# -> f1 /@ #] &@Pick[list, sel]]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a great syntactic sugar:

```
MapIf[function_, list_] := Map[
   With[{r = function[#]}, If[r =!= Null, r, #]]&, list];

MapIf[function_, list_, test_] := Map[
   If[test[#], function[#], #]&, list];

In[180]:= MapIf[f, # > 3 &, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]

Out[180]= {1, 2, 3, f[4], f[5]}
```

Comment: It seems the 3-param definition of MapIf should flip the order of list_ and test_ , that is, MapIf[function_, test_, list_] := ... produces the expected result, whereas running as-is gives     MapIf[f, # > 3 &, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]   ->   (If[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}[#1], f[#1], #1] &)[#1 > 3] &