# Map-Thread-Through-Apply a list of functions onto a list of (lists of) values

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of functions:

```
fns = {f, g, h}
```

and a list of triples:

```
list = {{1,2,3},{11,22,33},{111,222,333},{1111,2222,3333}};
```

What's the best way to apply `f` to the first element of every triple, `g` to the second elements, and `h` to the last elements?

```
{
  {f[1], g[2], h[3]}, 
  {f[11], g[22], h[33]}, 
  {f[111], g[222], h[333]}, 
  {f[1111], g[2222], h[3333]}
}
```

(I know a few methods, but I'm looking for more.)

Comment: Suddenly everybody is using `Compose`; I think I [started a trend.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9797/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard [`Compose[]` is supposed to be an **obsolete** function, though.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compose.html).

Comment: @J.M. I know, which is why I'm amused that three answers below are using it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You sure it were you? Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697640/split-pane-gui-object/7699580#7699580), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741671/unevaluated-form-of-ai/8746584#8746584), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432354/create-a-symbolic-orthonormal-matrix-in-mathematica/8433260#8433260),for example :-).

Comment: @Leonid three replies come to mind:  (1) You don't think I actually *read* all that stuff do you? (2) I'm senile and I have no idea why they trust me with the keys. (3) Great minds think alike. -- Take your pick.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'dpick #3 :-). Besides, neither of us started the trend, it was started by the designer of mma, responsible for Compose (in this case, most likely Stephen Wolfram himself).

Comment: @J.M. I think it might be obsolete because it feels somewhat misnamed.  A shame, because it is squatting on a decent shorter name for `Composition` -- a mistake I still make from time to time when writing code.  The semantics of `Compose` are also a bit of a mixed bag: part Lisp `funcall` and part `Composition`.  The former meaning (`#@##2&`) is what people are using for this question, and I wouldn't mind seeing another name given to that -- much like `Identity` is a name for `#&`.  `Call` perhaps, or the lengthy `FunctionCall`?

Comment: @WReach, if my opinion counts for anything, I was bummed when they "replaced" `Compose[]` with `Composition[]`. Oh well...

Comment: Why did't anybody use Composite instead of Compose if indeed, Compose is being retired?

Comment: @Gary I presume you mean `Composition` -- it wouldn't really be applicable here as I see it.

Comment: Brett, it's your perogative to Accept whatever answer you want, but why did you select what appears to be an inferior method?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My reasons are completely irrational and focus more on what I consider elegant or interesting approaches rather  than absolute speed.  So I liked the approaches that used `Inner` and `ListCorrelate` over faster ones that used `Map`.  (I should also say that my final code will probably end up using Leonid's double Transpose.  And for what it's worth, there was also much up-voting involved on my part prior to finally accepting an answer.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about:

```
Inner[#2@#1 &, list, fns, List, 2]
```

or

```
Inner[Compose, fns, Transpose@list, List] (* Note, that Compose is obsolete *)
```

or

```
MapIndexed[fns[[Last@#2]]@#1 &, list, {2}]
```

or

```
ListCorrelate[{fns}, list, {1, -1}, {}, Compose, Sequence]
```

or

```
MapThread[Compose, {Array[fns &, Length@list], list}, 2]
```

or

```
ReplacePart[list, {i_, j_} :> fns[[j]][list[[i, j]]]]
```

or

```
list // Query[All, Thread[Range@Length@fns -> fns]]
```

or (cheating a little)

```
list // Query[All, {1 -> f, 2 -> g, 3 -> h}]
```

Comment: The `Inner` approach is the one I'm currently using.

Comment: I added another method to make up for it :)

Comment: Like *J.M.* says `Compose` has been obsolete since more than 20(!) years.

Comment: @steven, that's nothing; *Mathematica* 8 still has `Release[]`, and that has been deprecated far longer...

Comment: @J.M. "far longer" seems a bit difficult; according to the documentation center both are obsolete since version 2 (1991), and I can't imagine functions being deprecated starting version 1 :-).

Comment: @steven, maybe my memory's going, but it was kind of deprecated by version 1.2 ... maybe a Wolfram employee can confirm.

Answer (score 26):

What about

```
Map[MapThread[Compose, {fns, #}] &, list]
```

or

```
Transpose@MapThread[Map, {fns, Transpose[list]}]
```

Comment: Like *J.M.* says `Compose` has been obsolete since more than 20(!) years.

Comment: @stevenvh And so :-) ?

Comment: @steven, it may not exactly be recommended, but it still works. From an old army saw: "if a dumb thing works, then it ain't dumb."

Comment: @Leonid - The documentation center doesn't give any description of it any more, so how can it help OP, when he doesn't know what it does? (You don't explain it either)

Comment: @stevenvh Fair enough. I will add the description. But I guess the OP would know what it is, in this particular case, given his affiliation :-)

Comment: So I wonder, what should one write instead of the obsolete `Compose` in e.g. `Inner[Compose, fns, Transpose@list, List]`, if one does not want to use `Slot`-s? What the heck is the full name of the function application function, if there is any??

Comment: @IstvánZachar I'd still use `Compose`. I do use it  myself sometimes in such cases. It may be obsolete, but I very much doubt that the support for it would ever be discontinued.

Answer (score 23):

The OP said: "I know a few methods, but I'm looking for more." so here are my offerings for the sake of interest.  The second is intentionally a bit convoluted.  The third may actually be of interest as the method could be used for in-place modification.

```
With[{op = MapIndexed[#[Slot @@ #2] &, fns]}, op & @@@ list]

Fold[RotateLeft@MapAt[#2, #, 1] &, list\[Transpose], Function[x, x /@ # &] /@ fns]\[Transpose]

Module[{x = list\[Transpose]}, Table[x[[i]] = fns[[i]] /@ x[[i]], {i, Length@x}]; x\[Transpose]]
```

Or for in-place modification:

```
With[{x = list}, Table[x[[All, i]] = fns[[i]] /@ x[[All, i]], {i, Length@First@x}]; x]
```

This post is primarily to provide the service of comparative timings. I will be using *Mathematica* 7.

Timings using an array of 1.5 million Integers and three inert symbolic heads:

```
fns = {f, g, h};
list = RandomInteger[1*^6, {500000, 3}];
times = timeAvg[#[]] & /@ methods;
BarChart[MapThread[Labeled, {times, methods}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using an array of Reals and three trig functions:

```
fns = {Sin, Cos, Csc};
list = RandomReal[1*^6, {500000, 3}];
times = timeAvg[#[]] & /@ methods;
BarChart[MapThread[Labeled, {times, methods}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To explore performance with different shapes here is as above but with 500 random trig functions:

```
fns = RandomChoice[{Sin, Cos, Sec, Csc, Tan}, 500];
list = RandomReal[1*^6, {5000, 500}];
times = timeAvg[#[]] & /@ methods;
BarChart[MapThread[Labeled, {times, methods}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Functions as I named and used them:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := 
  Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

leonid1[] := Map[MapThread[Compose, {fns, #}] &, list]
leonid2[] := Transpose@MapThread[Map, {fns, Transpose[list]}]
rm1[]     := Replace[list, x_List :> MapIndexed[fns[[First@#2]]@#1 &, x], {1}]
rm2[]     := MapIndexed[fns[[First@#2]]@#1 &, #] & /@ list
kguler1[] := Inner[#1@#2 &, fns, #, List] & /@ list
kguler2[] := Inner[Compose, fns, #, List] & /@ list
wreach1[] := Inner[#2@#1 &, list, fns, List, 2]
wreach2[] := MapIndexed[fns[[Last@#2]]@#1 &, list, {2}]
wreach3[] := ListCorrelate[{fns}, list, {1, -1}, {}, Compose, Sequence]
wreach4[] := MapThread[Compose, {Array[fns &, Length@list], list}, 2]
wizard1[] := With[{op = MapIndexed[#[Slot @@ #2] &, fns]}, op & @@@ list]
wizard2[] := Fold[RotateLeft@MapAt[#2, #, 1] &, list\[Transpose], Function[x, x /@ # &] /@ fns]\[Transpose]
wizard3[] := Module[{x = list\[Transpose]}, Table[x[[i]] = fns[[i]] /@ x[[i]], {i, Length@x}]; x\[Transpose]]

methods = {leonid1, leonid2, rm1, rm2, kguler1, kguler2, wreach1, 
   wreach2, wreach3, wreach4, wizard1, wizard2, wizard3};
```

Answer (score 15):

```
Inner[#1@#2 &, fns, #, List] & /@ list
(*or *)
Inner[Compose, fns, #, List] & /@ list
% //TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Like *J.M.* says `Compose` has been obsolete since more than 20(!) years.

Comment: @stevenvh And it still works just fine, thank you. :D

Answer (score 11):

Another solution using `MapIndexed` and —

1. **`Replace`**:

   ```
   Replace[list, x : {_, _, _} :> MapIndexed[fns[[First@#2]]@#1 &, x], {1}]
   ```
2. **`Map`**:

   ```
   MapIndexed[fns[[First@#2]]@#1 &, #] & /@ list
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Here is another option using `Compose`:

```
Compose@@@Thread@{fns, #}&/@list
```

or with `Function`:

```
Thread[fns~Function[{f, v}, f@v, Listable]~#] & /@ list
```

Answer (score 7):

This is not a complete answer, but I am posting it as one so it does not get lost in the comments. `Compose` has returned in Version 12 as `Construct`, so all solutions can now be implemented with supported and documented functions.

Comment: Maybe should note that `Compose[f, x]` is equivalent to `Construct[f, x]` but `Compose[f, g, x]` is not equivalent to `Construct[f, g, x]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, thank you for noting this. I suspect from watching the design reviews online that there may be a builtin function that will solve this whole problem in 12.1 as it seems to have caught Wolfram's attention.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry for bothering an old question. It's not that fast but here is one way with the newer [`Threaded`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Threaded.html):

```
Function[, #1@#2, {Listable}][Threaded@fns, list]
```

Comment: (+1) I like updates like this one!!!

Comment: @bmf Thanks! Though not the fastest, the performance of `Threaded` is not bad. I guess people on this site haven't got into habit of using it (yet).

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution:

```
Transpose[Activate[Thread[Inactive[Map][fns, Transpose[list]]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another way:

```
Transpose@Diagonal[(Thread /@ Through[fns[#]]) & /@ (Transpose@list)]

(*{{f[1], g[2], h[3]}, {f[11], g[22], h[33]}, {f[111], g[222], h[333]}, {f[1111], g[2222], h[3333]}}*)
```

Or using `Outer`:

```
Transpose@Diagonal[Transpose@*Thread@*Through /@ Outer[fns @@ #1 &@*List,Transpose@list]]
```

Comment: Nicely done mate - comment/reminder to upvote - I used max votes today

Comment: Hi, mate! We are starting the year with a lot of energy :-)