# Produce {f[x],g[y],h[z]} in as many ways as possible

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists of equal lengths but for my task I will use 3-element lists , namely `{x,y,z}` and `{f,g,h}`. The first contains variables and the second functions.

I want to produce `{f[x],g[y],h[z]}` with input the above lists in as many ways as possible.

Until now I have devised the following ones:

```
Inner[#1[#2]&,{f,g,h},{x,y,z},List]
```

and

```
MapThread[#1[#2]&,{{f,g,h},{x,y,z}}]
```

As pointed out , there is a very similar thread at wolfram's community.

If I come up with more solutions I will add them here.

**Update**

I am updating with the one-liners. In *Wolfram's Community* forum there are also solutions changing Attributes or using Append but I will omit them here.

```
MapThread[#1[#2]&,{{f,g,h},{x,y,z}}]

Inner[#1[#2]&,{f,g,h},{x,y,z},List]

Diagonal[Through/@Distribute[{f,g,h}[{x,y,z}],List]

MapThread[Compose,{{f,g,h},{x,y,z}}]
```

`Apply[List,{f,g,h}.{x,y,z}/.Times->(Operate[##1,0]&)]` and `Apply[List,{f,g,h}.{x,y,z}/.Times->(#1[#2]&)]` work only because f,g,h are before x,y,z in alphabetical order as very well pointed out by @andre

```
 Apply[Compose,Thread[{{f,g,h},{x,y,z}}],{1}]

 (#1[[1]][#1[[2]]]&)/@Transpose[{{f,g,h},{x,y,z}}]
```

Comment: [Distributing a list of heads over a list of arguments](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/113769)

Comment: Thanks @ssch this is exactly what I was searching.

Comment: I would not delete - as entry point for the community thread it should be useful.

Comment: Ok , thank you @Yves Klett , I will edit the post and if any more solutions come to my attention (beside that of the community's) i will add them.

Comment: `Apply[List, {f, g, h}.{x, y, z} /. Times -> (Operate[##1, 0] &)]` works only because f,g,h are before x,y,z in alphabetical order. The problem is  the commutativity of `Times`. For example `Apply[List, {f, g, h}.{a, y, z} /. Times -> (Operate[##1, 0] &)]`doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @andre so this solution would be valid for Subscripts ? There is the same problem with Apply[List, {f, g, h}.{a, y, z} /. Times -> (#1[#2] &)] also

Comment: Subscript? I don't understand.

Comment: I am sorry I meant Array,  `{f[1],f[2],f[3]}`  and `{x[1],x[2],x[3]}` could be used (of course f is still before x in alphabetical order).

Comment: @kuba thank you for the edit. I needed to break the code above to put some extra comments.

Comment: This is a subset of: [Map-Thread-Through-Apply a list of functions onto a list of (lists of) values](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11298/121).  I would like to close it as a duplicate unless you can argue that I do not.

Comment: @tchronis It works with {f[1],f[2],f[3]} and {x[1],x[2],x[3]} but one shouldn't rely on this kind of code.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree the link above leads to a broader set of solutions. Give me just a few minutes to copy and see if I can contribute in the link above sometime in the near future.

Comment: `Apply@@@Transpose[{...}]` - there is such example but with different syntax.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sure this is a subset of the Above Link but many of the solutions need small changes because they are applied in a single element list {{x,y,z}} - so I am not sure if my post finally helps anybody here. I would like to leave this decision to you. Thanks.

Comment: I am going to close this.  I will not delete your question and you may use it to add any additional solutions you find or construct.

Comment: Also related: [(9784)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9784/121)

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard , 9784 is nice but for only one function `f`.

Comment: Yes, I know; I just put the link here for future visitors.