# Is there a built-in function to map a list of heads to a list of data?

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Assume that this built-in function is called `func`.
What I want is

```
func[{f,g},{a,b,c}]
```

will return the following result:

```
{{f[a],f[b],f[c]},{g[a],g[b],g[c]}}
```

I can achieve this by defining a function myself:

```
myfunc[functions_List, data_] := 
    Table[Map[fn, data], {fn, functions}];
```

But is there some built-in function to achieve the same result?

(I have to admit that, after months intermittent reading of `The Mathematica Book` my knowledge is still very limited compared with what exist unknown in the sea.)

Comment: Related: [(9784)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9784), [(11298)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11298)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Update

Well I guess I should retire for the evening to a less brain-intensive activity as apparently I can't think clearly.  One could of course use `Outer:`

```
Outer[Compose, {f, g}, {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {{f[a], f[b], f[c]}, {g[a], g[b], g[c]}}
> ```

However I recommend that you do not do this as you will not gain the auto-compilation of `Map`, meaning this method will often be slower.  Please see [Leonid's explanation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21863/121) of this issue.

#### Old, half-awake answer

As far as I can remember there is no function that does specifically this in one step.  I have used a more terse version of your own solution myself:

```
myMap[fns_, data_] := # /@ data & /@ fns

myMap[{f, g}, {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {{f[a], f[b], f[c]}, {g[a], g[b], g[c]}}
> ```

There are of course many alternatives, e.g.:

```
Thread /@ Through[{f, g}[{a, b, c}]]
```

> ```
> {{f[a], f[b], f[c]}, {g[a], g[b], g[c]}}
> ```

However this inferior because it first evaluates to:

> ```
> {f[{a, b, c}], g[{a, b, c}]}
> ```

Which means that `f` and `g` may evaluate before the operation is complete.  One could add an `Unevaluated`, `Hold`, `Inactive` etc., but that seems like pointless complexity.

Just for fun we could make use of the operator form of `Map` in version 10:

```
Through[(Map /@ {f, g})[{a, b, c}]]
```

> ```
> {{f[a], f[b], f[c]}, {g[a], g[b], g[c]}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks, they are very helpful informations!

Comment: `Compose` becomes superseded by `Composition`, which gives `f*@a` instead of `f[a]`. Hence a bit concerned when MMA will completely remove `Compose`...

Comment: @xiaohuamiao I have no special insight into the situation but others more knowledgeable than I (e.g. Leonid Shifrin) have indicated that it is unlikely that such functions will ever be removed.  If it *were* to happen one could define something like `Compose = #[#2] &` in an initialization file to keep compatibility with existing code.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's any built-in function to do this, but here is an alternative:

```
myFunc[func_, data_] := Transpose[Through[func[#]] & /@ data]
```

Then

```
myFunc[{f, g, h}, {a, b, c}]
```

> `{{f[a], f[b], f[c]}, {g[a], g[b], g[c]}, {h[a], h[b], h[c]}}`

Answer (score 4):

Using `Query`

```
Query[Transpose, {f, g}] @ {a, b, c}
```

{{f[a], f[b], f[c]}, {g[a], g[b], g[c]}}

Answer (score 3):

`Outer[#1 @ #2 &, {f, g}, {a, b, c}]`
or
`Outer[Construct, {f, g}, {a, b, c}]` can do.