# Applying corresponding elements of a list to a list of functions

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, inner

I found this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11298/map-thread-through-apply-a-list-of-functions-onto-a-list-of-lists-of-values) which applying a function to a list of functions and arguments. I thought I could change my code with a table to something more elegant. I am not wedded to the `Inner` so if anyone has a different idea, I'm open to it.

My original `Table` code is

```
Table[ArgMin[{f[[i]][z], {z} \[Element] 
 Interval[{Min[lim[[i]]], Max[lim[[i]]]}]}, z], {i, Length[f]}];
```

and the `Inner` code I tried was

```
Inner[ArgMin[#1[z], {z} \[Element] Interval[{Min[#2], Max[#2]}], z] &, f, lim, List, 1]
```

However, The new code puts out the equivalent of `Transpose[lim]`.

An example input is

```
f = {Cos[#] &, Abs[#] &};
lim = {{0, \[Pi]}, {-1, 1}};
```

Edit:

Is there someway to get the same output as with the table, without using `Table`?

Comment: What is your question here exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Inner` doesn't work here because `f` and `lim` have different tensor shape, so `Inner` does generalized matrix multiplication rather than vector inner product.

The most straightforward method is probably using `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[ArgMin[{#1@z, {z} ∈ Interval@MinMax@#2}, z] &, {f, lim}]
```

(`MinMax` is a version 10.1 shorthand function.)

If you want to get `Inner` to work you can feed it the one-dimensional list of intervals rather than the two-dimensional list of endpoints:

```
Inner[ArgMin[#1[z], {z} ∈ #2, z] &, f, Interval /@ MinMax /@ lim, List]
```

The `MapThread` method can also be converted into a method using `Transpose` and `Apply`:

```
ArgMin[{#1@z, {z} ∈ Interval@MinMax@#2}, z] & @@@ Transpose@{f, lim}
```

Comment: The only odd thing is I have v10 but don't have `MinMax` besides that it works.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I guess it's v10.1.