# How to sort list of mixed types of elements with each type a specified canonical order?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

For example, here is a list

```
{{1, "u"}, {6, "d"}, {3, "u"}, {4, "d"}, {2, "u"}, {5, "u"}, {3, 
  "d"}, {1, "d"}, {4, "u"}, {2, "d"}, {5, "d"}, {6, "u"}}
```

The default canonical order for integer is 1,2,3,4

The default canonical order for letters is a,b,c,d,

But now I want to sort this list according to canonical integer order while "u" should be ordered before "d", how to achieve this easily?

The example list I gave here has a good structure, so can be solved with specific tricks. But the problem is general. **How to sort list of mixed types of elements with each type a specified canonical order?**

Comment: I'd define a function which assigns appropriate "weights" to elements then use `SortBy` or `KeySortBy` after casting the `List` as an `Association` (which I expect is faster, but haven't verified empirically).

Comment: `SortBy[list, {First, Switch[#[[2]], "u", -1, "d", 1] &}]` for your particular example works.

Comment: Will your real world usage always only be "u" and "d" or will it be other letters of the alphabet?

Comment: Are you by any chance building a Wick Contraction generator?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch other letter is possible, and even strings, they serve as labels

Comment: @evanb Nope. I guess you have some usual idea about my question. Want to post an answer :) Though I am not doing wick contraction right now, but I probably need it in future, because I am doing physics.

Comment: @matheorem I just ask because I have a decently-easy-to-use Wick Contractor for lattice QCD, but I'd rather not post it on line in its entirety :)

Comment: @matheorem you should make that clear in your question because some answers have focussed on "u" and "d" only.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I am sorry, I thought this sentence `How to sort list of mixed types of elements with each type a specified canonical order?` is a general statement

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch But some answer is quite general and I learned from your answer too, thank you!

Answer (score 15):

```
SortBy[l, {First@#, -ToCharacterCode@Last@#} &]
(*{{1, "u"}, {1, "d"}, {2, "u"}, {2, "d"}, {3, "u"}, {3, "d"}, {4, 
  "u"}, {4, "d"}, {5, "u"}, {5, "d"}, {6, "u"}, {6, "d"}}*)
```

Or the same, but slightly shorter code

```
SortBy[l, {#, -ToCharacterCode@#2} &@@#&]
```

**Edit**

The following uses the same sorting strategy but is much faster (by using [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11300/193)):

```
fns = {1000 # &, ToCharacterCode@# &};
l[[Ordering[Subtract @@@ Transpose@MapThread[Map, {fns, Transpose[l]}]]]]
```

Comment: using `ToCharacterCode`! upvote

Answer (score 7):

A simple approach giving the requested result is

```
SortBy[list, (#[[2]] /. {"u" -> 0, "d" -> 1}) + 100 #[[1]] &]    
(* {{1, "u"}, {1, "d"}, {2, "u"}, {2, "d"}, {3, "u"}, {3, "d"}, {4, "u"}, 
    {4, "d"}, {5, "u"}, {5, "d"}, {6, "u"}, {6, "d"}} *)
```

In fact, even simpler is

```
SortBy[list, (# /. {"u" -> 0, "d" -> 1}) &]
```

Simpler yet is

```
SortBy[list, (# /. "u" -> 0) &]
```

**Revised AbsoluteTiming with two new solutions**

With so many solutions, it may be of interest to know their respective `AbsoluteTiming`s, based on

```
list = Riffle[Map[{#, "u"} &, RandomSample[Range[100000]]], 
              Map[{#, "d"} &, RandomSample[Range[100000]]]];
```

Mike Honeychurch         `0.397657`

J.M. (comment)           `0.468703`

bbgodfrey (third solution) `0.589428`

belisarius is forth (first solution)      `0.811408`

Jack LaVigne            `11.2244`

Modifications of solutions by J.M. and Mike Honeychurch, respectively, are even faster.

```
SortBy[list, {First, Switch[#, "u", -1, "d", 1] &}]  (* 0.385315 *)

Flatten[Reverse[Partition[Sort[list], 2], 2], 1]  (* 0.25386 *)
```

Comment: I like this this one, clever! But why `"d" -> 1/10`, `"d" -> 1` is OK. A mistake?

Comment: @matheorem  You are correct.  `"d"` assigned any number bigger than that assigned to `"u"` works.  I carried forward the logic of my first solution without thinking.  Thanks for the correction.  I have simplified my solution accordingly.

Comment: For large lists `Sort` can often be slow. Using `Ordering` could possibly speed up my solution for your large test sample.

Answer (score 4):

Your limited example implies that you want to reverse the canonical order for the letters in position 2 so that "u" will appear before "d". I've assumed that all letters of the alphabet could appear in position 2 so if that is the case then this would do it:

```
Flatten[Reverse[GatherBy[Sort[list], First], 2], 1]
```

...but there is probably a more straight forward method, perhaps using `SortBy`.

**Edit**

As mentioned in comments with @bbgodfrey it is often more efficient to use `Ordering` for large lists rather than `Sort`. Also @bbgodfrey notes that `Partition` could be used instead of `GatherBy`.

```
Flatten[Reverse[Partition[list[[Ordering[list]]], 2], 2], 1]
```

Comment: Straightforward or not, your solution is remarkably fast, especially when `GatherBy` is replaced by `Partition`.

Comment: I just noticed a typo in my earlier comment, which is why I deleted it.  `Ordering[list]` should have been enclosed in double-brackets, not single ones.  I corrected my error in your answer.  Unfortunately, with the correction `list[[Ordering[list]]]` offers no advantage over `Sort[list]`, although `Partition` still does.  Sorry.

Comment: @bbgodfrey yes you're right. Maybe `Sort` has been rewritten in recent versions. Certainly in older version `Ordering ` used to smash `Sort`.

Comment: On the other hand, `list[[Flatten[Reverse[Partition[Ordering[list], 2], 2]]]]` offers a noticeable speed advantage, probably because `Reverse` is acting on indices rather than on `list` elements.  Of course, your original solution  with `GatherBy` offers a flexibility that most other solutions lack.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I think there is enough information now to satisfy the OP

Answer (score 2):

I think a general solution is to perform the first test followed by the second test in case of ties.

```
Sort[list, first[test] || tie[first] && second[test]]
```

For your specific example

```
list = {{1, "u"}, {6, "d"}, {3, "u"}, {4, "d"}, {2, "u"}, {5, "u"}, 
        {3, "d"}, {1, "d"}, {4, "u"}, {2, "d"}, {5, "d"}, {6, "u"}}
```

With the integers sorted on the first element and then "u" preceding "d" for the second element this translates to:

```
Sort[list, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] ||
    (#1[[1]] == #2[[1]] && OrderedQ[{#2[[2]], #1[[2]]}]) &]
```

which gives

```
{{1, "u"}, {1, "d"}, {2, "u"}, {2, "d"}, {3, "u"}, {3, "d"},
  {4, "u"}, {4, "d"}, {5, "u"}, {5, "d"}, {6, "u"}, {6, "d"}}
```

Comment: I believe bbgodfrey's answer is better. I see that in the documentation for `SortBy` it states. ***SortBy[list, {f1, f2}...} breaks ties by successively using the values obtained from the fi.***

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer the question (not the specific example), you could create a recursive function.  It would take a list of comparison functions, compare the first elements using the first function, and only use the rest if the first elements are the same.

```
ClearAll[compare];
compare[a_, b_, test_] /; Length@a == 1 := test[[1]][a[[1]], b[[1]]];
compare[a_, b_, test_] := test[[1]][a[[1]], b[[1]]] ||
   a[[1]] == b[[1]] && compare[Rest@a, Rest@b, Rest@test];
```

In action:

```
Sort[list, compare[##, {Less, Greater}] &]
```

> `{{1, "u"}, {1, "d"}, {2, "u"}, {2, "d"}, {3, "u"}, {3, "d"},
>     {4, "u"}, {4, "d"}, {5, "u"}, {5, "d"}, {6, "u"}, {6, "d"}}`

And it works with elements of any length, with any sort of comparison, e.g.

```
r = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {1000, 3}];
Sort[r, compare[##, {Less, Greater, Abs[5 - #1] < Abs[5 - #2] &}] &]
```