# How to apply a function to an expression?

Tags: functional-style

What is the name for the function `#1[#2]&`?

I would call it `Apply`, so that `Apply[Sin,2]` is `Sin[2]`, but the real *Mathematica*'s `Apply` does a different thing.

Comment: Perhaps `Operate`?  E.g., `Operate[Sin,2,0]`.

Comment: `Nest[Sin,2,1]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be `Compose`:

```
Compose[Sin, 2]
(* Sin[2] *)

#1[#2] &[Sin, 2]
(* Sin[2] *)
```

Comment: You must have been using Mma for a long time!  One cannot even get documentation for `Compose` any more.

Comment: +1 as `Compose` is the closest thing we have.  In the comments of [(11298)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11298/map-thread-through-apply-a-list-of-functions-onto-a-list-of-lists-of-values/11315#comment34123_11298) there is some discussion about 1) a name for `#1[#2]&` or, more generally, for `#1[##2]&`; 2) whether `Compose` is a good name for that operation; and 3) the obsolescence of `Compose`.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is anonymous. You can use it like this.

```
#1[#2]&[Sin, 30 °]
```

> `1/2`

You can also give it a name.

```
apply = #1[#2]&;
```

then

```
apply[Sin, 30 °]
```

> `1/2`