# Elegant way for element-wise application of a list of functions

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

For given functions $f,g,\cdots$ I want to define a pure function that, when applied to any list $\{x,y,\cdots\}$ (of the same length as $\{f,g,\cdots\}$), produces $\{f[x],g[y],\cdots\}$. Two ways to achieve this are

```
{f@#[[1]],g@#[[2]],...} &
```

and

```
MapThread[
   #1[#2] & (* or Apply[#1,{#2}] & *),
   {{f,g,...},#}
] &
```

With all of Mathematica's built in functions, however, I would be surprised if there does not exist a slicker way to do this. Thus my **question** is: is there a more elegant way to do the above?

For concreteness let's take just to functions $\{f,g\}$ and apply it to $\{x,y\}$, yet I'm hoping for an answer that generalizes to more than two functions.

Although I would expect that this has been asked here before I cannot find it.

Comment: My first approach would have been the `MapThread` you show here.

Comment: Yeah, I feel like this is one of the things that `MapThread` was *designed* for.

Comment: For the first argument of `MapThread`, you could use `Compose` rather than a pure function: `MapThread[Compose, {{f, g, ...}, #}] &`.

Comment: @xavier: Thanks, that's nice indeed! If you turn your suggestion into an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @JulesLamers Please feel free to make it an answer if it satisfies you. (It is also OK to accept one's own answer.)

Comment: Very nearly a duplicate of [(11298)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11298/121)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encouraged by the comments I think that the following slight improvement, suggested by xavier (user31159), of the second attempt I included in my question is (at least quite close to) what I was hoping for:

```
MapThread[
  Compose,
  {{f,g,...},#}
] &
```

Thanks for the other suggestions as well!

Comment: Altho `Compose[]` is obsolete; it's quite nice. Anyway: `Inner[Compose, lst1, lst2, List]`, if you want something slot-free.

Answer (score 6):

Let lst1 be the list of heads of your functions:

```
lst1={f,g,h};
```

for example they may be `Cos`, `Sin`, `Exp` and so on, and lst2 is the list of numbers to which you want to apply the heads:

```
lst2={a,b,c};
```

A most simple way seems me to be this:

```
    Transpose[{lst1, lst2}] /. {x_, y_} -> x[y]

(*   {f[a], g[b], h[c]}  *)
```

Another way would be to first introduce a function:

```
   s[x_, y_] := x[y]
```

and with its use do this:

```
MapThread[s, {lst1, lst2}]

(*  {f[a], g[b], h[c]}  *)
```

or this:

```
Inner[s, lst1, lst2, List]

{f[a], g[b], h[c]}
```

One can probably find something else, but in the moment I do not see.

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

I think the `MapThread` approach is already elegant. Anyway, the following is the shortest solution so far:

```
#@#2 & @@@ ArcTan[{f, g}, #] &
```

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for using ArcTan?

Comment: @JulesLamers No, if you use `List`, then you only got `{f[g], x[y]}`. I use `ArcTan` because it owns `Listable` attribute and seems not to evaluate to other things even if its 2nd argument is some special number e.g. `ArcTan[f, 0]` still outputs `ArcTan[f, 0]`.

Comment: (You're right, my suggestion to use List instead of ArcTan was incorrect; I edited my comment accordingly)

Answer (score 2):

One can use the `Listable` attribute to apply a list of function to lists of arguments. One can extend it easily to multiple lists of arguments (see last example).

Either via `Function`:

```
Function[{x, y}, x[y], Listable][{f, g, h}, {x, y, z}]
(*  {f[x], g[y], h[z]}  *)
```

Or via a symbol:

```
Block[{threadApply},
 SetAttributes[threadApply, Listable];
 threadApply[f_, x___] := f[x];
 threadApply[{f, g, h}, {x, y, z}]
 ]
(*  {f[x], g[y], h[z]}  *)
```

With the symbolic form, it's easy to deal with an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
Block[{threadApply},
 SetAttributes[threadApply, Listable];
 threadApply[f_, x___] := f[x];
 threadApply[{f, g, h}, {a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]
 ]
(*  {f[a, x], g[b, y], h[c, z]}  *)

Block[{threadApply},
 SetAttributes[threadApply, Listable];
 threadApply[f_, x___] := f[x];
 threadApply[{f, g, h}]
 ]
(*  {f[], g[], h[]}  *)
```

This is also possible with a slight modification of the OP's original `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[#1[##2] &, {{f, g, h}, {a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}]
(*  {f[a, x], g[b, y], h[c, z]}  *)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for your answer! It's nice to see the versions with several arguments as well. Just a small question about the final version: why do you prefer `#1[##2]&` over `Compose`?

Comment: @JulesLamers You're welcome! Note that `Compose[f, a, x]` and `#1[##2]&[f, a, x]` are not the same. There's also this warning: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compose.html

Comment: As for the first of course you're quite right, I was thinking about the two-argument case. Regarding the latter I did see that warning, but since `Compose` and `Composition are different I'm not sure what to do with it; am I supposed not to use `Compose` any more?

Comment: @JulesLamers I suppose `Compose` is not going away (since it hasn't after nine version updates). I'll probably use `#1[#2]&` or `Composition` with `#` and `&` depending on the case. It's not a big deal to me, but I'd rather not have my code dependent on it. Even if it were to go away, it's easy enough to add a definition.