# Using Through on functions that take multiple arguments

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

I want simple syntax that results in this:

```
{{f[1, 2], g[1, 2]}, {f[3, 4], g[3, 4]}}
```

though I'm willing to settle for:

```
{{f[{1, 2}], g[{1, 2}]}, {f[{3, 4}], g[{3, 4}]}}
```

if that's easier somehow. (And for completeness, and Re: the answer I accepted, I'm also fine with the form

```
{{f[1, 2], f[3, 4]}, {g[1, 2], g[3, 4]}}
```

which differs from the original form by a simple `Transpose` anyway.)

I would expect the function `Through` to help here, but it doesn't seem able to work with functions that take multiple arguments. My naive attempt looks like this:

```
Through@{f, g}[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]

{f[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}], g[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]} (*out*)
```

which is clearly not what I want (as it does no threading over the arguments). If a function is defined to take one argument, then Through makes the most of that:

```
f[x_] := x^2
g[x_] := x^3
Through@{f, g}[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]

{{{1, 4}, {9, 16}}, {{1, 8}, {27, 64}}} (*out*)
```

(f and g now get applied to the lowest level, where there's only 1 argument.) So what I want is a way to get Through to 'make the most' of functions that take multiple arguments. Instead it gives me:

```
Clear[f, g]
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y
g[x_, y_] := x^3 + y
Through@{f, g}[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]

{f[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}], g[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]} (*out*)
```

Comment: Try `Through @* {f, g} /@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`.

Comment: I think that when you apply the functions `f` and `g` with only one argument each (the monomial case) you get the desired result not because `Through` works like you'd expect but because *Mathematica* can raise lists to (integer) powers

Comment: @J.M. I'm not sure if I understand; did you mean to type `Through@{f, g}[#] & /@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`?

Comment: @user, I used composition `@*` instead of application `@`; the former shortcut only became available in recent versions. What version are you using?

Comment: I will have to look it up-I'm currently on ver9.Thanks!

Comment: Related: [(11298)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11298/121)

Comment: Could use `Through@*{Apply[f], Apply[g]} /@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}` to get rid of the inner lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

Apply[#, list, {1}] & /@ {f, g}
```

> {{3, 13}, {3, 31}}

Or with the operator form of `Map`:

```
Map[Apply[#, list, {1}] &] @ {f, g}
```

Or in terse notation:

```
# @@@ list & /@ {f, g}
```

Comment: Though several people gave good answers, I like yours best for both simplicity and that it gives the (slightly) preferred output that I mentioned at the beginning of my post.

Comment: @Max This does not produce the form you requested, {{f, f}, {g, g}} rather than {{f, g}, {f, g}}.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You're right. But it so happens that difference isn't important to me (and besides it's a simple `Transpose` away) -- I'll edit my question to reflect that. And for future readers, I imagine this answer could still be the most convenient because it works with the standard function form f[x,y], rather than needing a re-definition f[{x_,y_}]:=f[x,y] as the other answers do.

Comment: Though @Carl Woll gave a modification to 
J.M.'s comment that makes it usable with the standard f[x,y] form as well.

Comment: @Max, right, Carl is using level-1 `Apply[]` (`@@@`) in his instead of `Map[]` (`/@`) in mine, which did expect lists as arguments.

Answer (score 8):

I like using [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot) free notation, so the following appeals to me:

```
Through @* {f, g} @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

> {{f[1, 2], g[1, 2]}, {f[3, 4], g[3, 4]}}

And for the OP using version 9:

```
Through /@ {f, g} @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

> {{f[1, 2], g[1, 2]}, {f[3, 4], g[3, 4]}}

Also, the short hand `@*` was introduced in M10, but you can still use the long hand in earlier versions:

```
Composition[Through, {f, g}] @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

> {{f[1, 2], g[1, 2]}, {f[3, 4], g[3, 4]}}

Comment: There's just something nice about keeping things slot-free... :)

Answer (score 3):

```
func[x_List] :=  Module[{},
  Map[Through[{f, g}[#] ] &, x]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Comap`:** (since v14.0, 2023)

```
Comap[{f,g},#]&/@{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

> {{f[{1,2}],g[{1,2}]},{f[{3,4}],g[{3,4}]}}

---

**Using `ComapApply`:** (since v14.0, 2023)

```
ComapApply[{f,g},#]&/@{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

> {{f[1,2],g[1,2]},{f[3,4],g[3,4]}}

Comment: `Comap` and `ComapApply` have operator forms: `Comap[{f, g}] /@ ...`

Answer (score 2):

Using `Query`

```
Query[All, {f, g}] @ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

> {{f[{1, 2}], g[{1, 2}]}, {f[{3, 4}], g[{3, 4}]}}

Answer (score 2):

Using `Tuples` and `SplitBy`:

```
Thread@SplitBy[#1 @@ #2 & @@@ Tuples[{{f, g}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}], Head]
```

> `{{f[1, 2], g[1, 2]}, {f[3, 4], g[3, 4]}}`