# Is Depth[x, Heads->True] historical?

Tags: bugs, options, core-language, documentation, undocumented

I randomly found that `Depth` has a boolean option called `Heads`:

```
In[1]:= Depth[1, 2, 3, 4]
During evaluation of In[7]:= Depth::nonopt: Options expected (instead of 4) beyond position 1 in Depth[1,2,3,4]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules. >>
Out[1]= Depth[1, 2, 3, 4]

In[2]:= Options[Depth]
Out[2]= {Heads -> False}
```

This is [not documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Depth.html) but seems to do what one would guess. For example, the reference explicitly says as a "possible issue" that

> `Depth` does not count depth in the head:
>
> ```
> In[1]:= Depth[h[{{{a}}}][x, y]]
> Out[1]= 2
> ```

but adding `Heads -> True` does exactly that:

```
In[2]:= Depth[h[{{{a}}}][x, y], Heads -> True]
Out[2]= 6
```

I wonder why the reference would go as far as saying that something that exists does not. Is this possibly a feature that used to be supported but (for whatever reason) is only kept for historical reasons, like the examples [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40982/how-is-the-mysterious-raw-function-used)? Can anyone confirm if the option is documented in some prior version?

Comment: It is a documentation bug -- this option did not exist originally but was implemented in version 8.0.0. Unfortunately, the documentation update hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Thank you, @ilian. I assume it's the same case for option `AllowHeads` of `Dimensions`. Should I report when I stumble upon similar cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per ilian's comment:

> It is a documentation bug -- this option did not exist originally but
>   was implemented in version 8.0.0. Unfortunately, the documentation
>   update hasn't happened yet.