# If statements with a Boolean

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation

If I have a vector {1,2,3}, I want to write an If statement, where if one of the positions is "1", it will perform a certain command.

```
test = {1, 2, 3}
# == 1 & /@ test 
If[# == 1 & /@ test == True, Print["Yes"], Print["no"]]
```

I get this as the output:

```
If[{True, False, False} == True, Print["Yes"], Print["no"]]
```

What am I doing wrong? I am new to Mathematica.

Comment: Use `MemberQ` to test if an element is in the list.

Comment: You should study the answers to this question [Map a function across a list conditionally](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/map-a-function-across-a-list-conditionally). In fact this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different solutions.  Here are a few:

```
test = {1, 2, 3}
# == 1 & /@ test

If[Or @@ Thread[# == 1 & /@ test == True], Print["Yes"], Print["no"]]
If[Or @@ (# == 1 & /@ test), Print["Yes"], Print["no"]]
If[MemberQ[test, 1], Print["Yes"], Print["No"]]
```

In my opinion these are in increasing order of clarity and good practice.