# How to select elements from a list by condition?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, conditional

Considering I have a list:

```
F = {f1, f2, f3, f4}
```

I want to perform exponent on the list

```
F = Power[#, 2]& /@ F
```

Now I want to do the same but with conditions. I want to perform `Power[#, 2]` on the elements of `F` that are not equal to `NULL` and the result of `Power[#, 2]` is not null.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Let's say I have

```
`A = {x, y, z}`

SomeAction[t_] := ...

SomeAction[#] &/@ A
```

Let's say `x = NULL`

As Harry commented  `SomeAction[#] &/@ Select[A, !(# === NULL) &]` will work only on `y` and `z`.

Let's also say that `SomeAction[y] = NULL`, and in this case I want to take the original `y`.

So I want to have following
`A` = ...`SomeAction[#] &/@ Select[A, !(# === NULL) &]`... be equivalent to

```
A = {y, SomeAction[z]}
```

Comment: something like `list = {1, 2, 3, Null, 4}; MapAt[#^2 &, list, 
 Position[list, x_ /; ! (x === Null), {1}, Heads -> False]]` ?

Comment: or `list = {1, 2, 3, Null, 4}; #^2 & /@ Select[list, ! (# === Null) &]` ?

Comment: Using the `Listable` attribute it usually much faster than using `Map` in this way, so you could try `F^2 /. Null^2 -> Null`.

Comment: @Harry right, something like that. But I would also like to control the resulting value, is it possible?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/map-a-function-across-a-list-conditionally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a construct you might like:

```
ifNot[f_, x_][y_] /; MatchQ[y, x] := y

ifNot[f_, x_][y_] := If[MatchQ[#, x], y, #] & @ f[y]
```

Example:

```
ifNot[#^2 &, 4] /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 9, 4, 25}
> ```

This is designed to work with patterns as well as literals for parameter `x`.

Comment: Shouldn't the fourth number in the answer to the example be 16? At least this is what I calculated in my head and what my Mathematica (11) gives me

Comment: @user1482714 I think you misunderstand the purpose of this function, which is: if the input is not "4" then square it, else return it unmodified.

Comment: Ohh, sorry, I was doing it with 2 for the `x_` argument, as this is what I needed in my application. You are completely right and my comment is wrong

Comment: @user1482714 No problem.  We all make mistakes; I seem to make more than my share of them.  Please continue to call me out when you believe you have spotted one of my mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

For example, here is a way to do what you want  with one single function.

In the following example, instead of `Null`, the "forbiden" value is `1`, and `someaction`is computing `Mod[x, 2]` function (which gives the remainder on division of x by 2).

Let's define `someaction`, Mathematica allows to do this :

```
someaction[x_List] := someaction /@ DeleteCases[x, 1];

someaction[x_] := Mod[x, 2] // Switch[#, 1, x, _, #] &
(* or also someaction[x_] := Mod[x, 2] /. {1 -> x}; *)
```

The first definition tells what `someaction` should do when its argument is a `List`: it deletes all `1`'s from the list and map on this new list the more general definition of `someaction`.
The second (more general) defintion of `someaction` tells the function to perform a particular computation (here `Mod[x,2]`) but if `1`is the result, it will be converted back to the argument (`x`).

**Test**

Let's say my test list is :

```
mylist={1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

then

```
someaction[mylist]
```

returns as expected

```
{0, 3, 0, 5, 0}
```

(for comparison : `Mod[#,2]/@mylist` returns `{1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}`)

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[myList];
myList = {{1, 3.128}, {2, 2.459}, {2, 6.287}, {7, 6.02}, {2, 15287}};

myListLength = Length[myList];
For[i = 1, i <= myListLength, i++,
 If[myList[[i, 1]] == 2, Print[myList[[i]]]]]
```