# ToUpperCases based on the original string

Tags: string-manipulation

Suppose I have a numberic string

```
str = "1234567456";
```

and another string called

```
nstr = "05eccead24";
```

I want to transform the non-digit character in `nstr`, that number corresponding to the same position in `str` is even, to upper cases. For example, the first non-digit character in `nstr` is `e`, and the position is `3`, the same postion in `str` is `3` which is odd, thus we keep it in lowercase. While for the next char `c` in `nstr`, the position is `4` and the corresponding character in `str` is `4`, which is even, so we should change it into uppercase.

The expected output should be:

```
"05eCcEaD24"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works:

```
MapThread[If[EvenQ[#2], ToUpperCase[#1], #1] &, {Characters @ "05eccead24", 
          IntegerDigits @ FromDigits @ "1234567456"}] // StringJoin

(* "05eCcEaD24" *)
```

Comment: Why community wiki?  Should I have added my method rather than posting separately?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, fret not, I've upvoted yours. I know mine will work, but I cannot test it at the moment (currently using the *gedanken* version).

Comment: It seems your method is orders of magnitude faster than mine.  If I cannot improve that I'll probably delete my answer.  Incidentally a line cannot start with `//`.  I hope you don't mind if I reformat your code.

Comment: I rewrote my code to avoid `StringReplacePart` and it is now ~2.9 times faster than this.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, I broke it up so that people don't have to scroll sideways, but I guess it's easy to misjudge things on a phone. (That's why I hate answering on a phone among other things… ;P)

Comment: I use a code width chosen to prevent scrolling for the majority of users.  If you would please add your configuration to [my survey](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/465/121) I can take it into account.

Comment: @J.M. Did you usually use the smart-phone to answer the question? I cannot download that app in China:(

Comment: @Shutao, I used Opera on an Android phone at the time I first wrote this answer.

Comment: @J.M. It's amazing. In general, I need a laptop to debug the *Mathematica* code.

Comment: You do know that quite a number of my answers last year were done without my having access to *Mathematica*, no? ;)

Comment: @J.M. That accounts for the milk in the coconut, I remember now :)

Answer (score 7):

*Edit*: I first used [`StringReplacePart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplacePart.html) but that function is slow when used for many replacements, much as [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) is.  I have rewritten my code using a method from [Map a function across a list conditionally](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/map-a-function-across-a-list-conditionally/9797#9797) and it is now orders of magnitude faster on long strings.

```
f[source_String, target_String] :=
  Module[{new = Characters @ target},
    (new[[#]] = ToUpperCase @ new[[#]]) & @
       StringPosition[source, Characters @ "02468"][[All, 1]];
    new <> ""
  ]

f["1234567456", "05eccead24"]
```

> ```
> "05eCcEaD24"
> ```

Comment: Maybe `DigitCharacter` and `EvenQ` can replace that long stream of text,but I have no ideal

Comment: @yode Literal patterns are typically faster however.

Comment: It is very good answer, but to me (I will not concern the time consumming stuff) @J.M. 's answer is more clean (and easy to understand).

Comment: @vanabel Thanks, and no problem; I like clean code too. :-)

Comment: I discovered that *Mathematica* is **not** fast...

Comment: @ShutaoTANG Certainly that is true in many areas, though there are also cases where *Mathematica* is competitively fast, usually when operating on packed arrays with calls to fast library (Intel MKL, etc.) functions.  However why are you commenting this here? *Edit*: Oh, I see you wrote a fast answer. +1 on that.  I wonder if I can improve on my pure-*Mathematica* method.

Answer (score 1):

Should be quick for large strings if you want to keep it native MMA:

```
upem[s_, t_] := 
  Module[{ss = Pick[Range@StringLength@s, EvenQ@ToCharacterCode[s]], 
    tc = ToCharacterCode@t},
   tc[[Intersection[ss, Pick[Range@StringLength@t, Unitize@Clip[tc, {97, 122}, {0, 0}],1]]]] -= 32;
   FromCharacterCode@tc];
```

E.g.

```
upem["1234567456", "05eccead24"]
```