# Apply function to list elements only if applicable

Tags: list-manipulation

Is it possible to apply function to list elements only if function applicable to element?
For example

```
{1.2, 3, {2.3, 5.4}, null, "fff"}
Floor[%]
```

gives

```
{1, 3, {2, 5} ,Floor[null], Floor["fff"]}
```

but I would like to get

```
{1, 3, {2, 5} ,null, "fff"}
```

Comment: `f[x_?NumericQ]:=Floor[x]; f[x_]:=x; f /@ list`.  Or `If[NumericQ[#], Floor[#], #]& /@ list`

Comment: Floor[%] go through nested lists. Is it possible for your solution?

Comment: `MapAll[f, list]` or `f//@ list`

Comment: Look up `Listable`.

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9784/5478

Answer (score 4):

It would be the combination of the comments of [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130401/apply-function-to-list-elements-only-if-applicable#comment352062_130401) and [David G. Stork](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130401/apply-function-to-list-elements-only-if-applicable#comment352066_130401)

```
list = {1.2, 3, {2.3, 5.4}, null, "fff"};
f[x_?NumericQ] := Floor[x]; f[x_] := x; f /@ list;
MapAll[f, list]
```

> {1, 3, {2, 5}, null, "fff"}

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Floor@# /. Floor -> Identity &;

f@{1.2, 3, {2.3, 5.4}, null, "fff"}
```

> {1, 3, {2, 5}, null, "fff"}

```
f@{1.2, 3, {2.3, "ff"}, null, "fff", Pi}
```

> {1, 3, {2, "ff"}, null, "fff", 3}

If the function returns unevaluated  when a 'non-applicable' input is passed, this approach is more convenient as it does not require detailed knowledge of the function's argument requirements.

```
ClearAll[h]
h[x_] := 500 /; PrimeQ[x]
h[x_] := 500 /; Divisible[x, 3]
h /@ Range[15] /. h -> Identity
```

> {1, 500, 500, 4, 500, 500, 500, 8, 500, 10, 500, 500, 500, 14, 500}

```
StringLength /@ {"abcabc", "bcdbc", 234} /. StringLength -> Identity
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>   {6, 5, 234}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1.2, 3, {2.3, "ff"}, null, "fff", Pi};

SetAttributes[floor, Listable]

floor[x_] := x /. a_?NumericQ :> Floor @ a

floor @ list
```

> {1, 3, {2, "ff"}, null, "fff", 3}