# Missing control for depth of Inner

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, linear-algebra, inner

Working on a mechanics problem, I stumbled on something peculiar:

Since `Inner` is a generalisation of `Dot`, it changes its behaviour depending upon the structure of the input lists.

```
Inner[f, {a, b}, {x, y}, g]
g[f[a, x], f[b, y]]
```

Pretty straight forward, right? Tuples drawn from the lists get inserted into `f` and all resulting expressions are input into `g`.

Now if we use two nested lists as input, the following happens:

```
Inner[f, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{w, x}, {y, z}}, g]
{{g[f[a, w], f[b, y]], g[f[a, x], f[b, z]]}, {g[f[c, w], f[d, y]], g[f[c, x], f[d, z]]}}
```

With some formatting applied:

```
Inner[f, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{w, x}, {y, z}}, g]//Column
{g[f[a, w], f[b, y]], g[f[a, x], f[b, z]]}
{g[f[c, w], f[d, y]], g[f[c, x], f[d, z]]}
```

Whereas I would expect an output like this:

```
Inner[f, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{w, x}, {y, z}}, g]
g[f[{a,b},{w,x}],f[{c,d},{y,z}]]
```

Is there something I'm missing? Is there a way to have `Inner` be agnostic about the heads of the expressions inside the lists? I already found the following workaround [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9235/21721):

```
Inner[f, Unevaluated /@ {{a, b}, {c, d}}, Unevaluated /@ {{w, x}, {y, z}}, g]
g[f[Unevaluated[{a, b}], Unevaluated[{w, x}]], f[Unevaluated[{c, d}], Unevaluated[{y, z}]]]
```

But, as stated, this seems like a crude workaround. 
To sum up my main question: Is there a function which generalizes the behaviour I'm looking for? And wouldn't it make sense for `Inner` to take an optional argument to control the depth on which it operates?

Comment: From the documentation for `Inner`, "Inner[f,Subscript[list, 1],Subscript[list, 2],g,n] contracts index n of the first tensor with the first index of the second tensor". It also states `Inner[f,{{a,b},{c,d}},{x,y},g]->{g[f[a,x],f[b,y]],g[f[c,x],f[d,y]]}`, so it is not unexpected behavior.

Comment: Relevant: [(9028)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9028/121) (I specifically link to my answer because I addressed level control.)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe `MapThread` gives the `levelspec` control you need:

```
lst = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{w, x}, {y, z}}};

g @@ MapThread[f, lst, 1]  (* or just g @@ MapThread[f, lst] -- thanks: Mr.W *)
(* g[f[{a,b},{w,x}],f[{c,d},{y,z}]] *)

g @@ MapThread[f, lst, 2]
(* g[{f[a,w],f[b,x]},{f[c,y],f[d,z]}] *)
```

or,

```
g @@ Thread[f @@ lst]
(* g[f[{a,b},{w,x}],f[{c,d},{y,z}]] *)
```

or

```
innerL1F = #4 @@ Thread[#[#2, #3]] &;

innerL1F[f, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{w, x}, {y, z}}, g]
(* g[f[{a,b},{w,x}],f[{c,d},{y,z}]] *)
```

Comment: I don't believe you need the `, 1` here.  Or am I forgetting something?

Comment: Thanks Mr.W, you are right. I was intending to show the level spec control we get; just posted an example where it happens to be the default levelspec.

Answer (score 4):

This probably doesn't address the full scope of your question but for the particular example you could use [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) and [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html):

```
ex1 = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
ex2 = {{w, x}, {y, z}};

g @@ MapThread[f, {ex1, ex2}]
```

> ```
> g[f[{a, b}, {w, x}], f[{c, d}, {y, z}]]
> ```

Or [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) and `Apply`:

```
g @@ f @@@ ({ex1, ex2}\[Transpose])
```

> ```
> g[f[{a, b}, {w, x}], f[{c, d}, {y, z}]]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something that works in higher dimensions but, for your 2D example can hack `Dataset` with `Transpose`:

```
{{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{w, x}, {y, z}}} // Dataset // Transpose // 
 Query[Apply@g, Apply@f] // Normal

(* g[f[{a, b}, {w, x}], f[{c, d}, {y, z}]] *)
```

Maybe `Inner` for order tensors can be emulated with some combo of arguments to `Transpose` applied at the right `Dataset` levels.

> Transpose[list,{n1,n2,…}] transposes list so that the k^(th) level in
>   list is the ^(th) level in the result.