# Elementwise dot multiplication for lists of matrices

Tags: matrix

I have lists of matrices and want to do element-wise matrix multiplication. Is there an easy way to do this that I've missed?

e.g: {A, B, C}.{X, Y, Z} = {A.X, B.Y, C.Z}

where A, B, C, X, Y, and Z are all matrices.

Comment: `C` is not a matrix. `C` is a reserved symbol for constants, you would be well advised to avoid using `C`, `D`, `E`, `I`, `K`, `N` and `O` except as their built in functions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
MapThread[Dot, {{A, B, C}, {X, Y, Z}}]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
{a, b, c, x, y, z} = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {6, 2, 2}]

bk = Dot @@@ Transpose@{{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}
jd = MapThread[Dot, {{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}]
bk == jd (*True*)
```

One can also use `Inner[Dot, {a, b, c}, {x, y, z}, List]` but you need to wrap lists in `Unevaluated`:

```
Inner[Dot, Unevaluated@{a, b, c}, Unevaluated@{x, y, z}, List]
```

See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9219/behavior-of-inner-depends-on-list-dimensions) for explanation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, it was sloppy of me to not check first.  FYI, you could shorten your first line by using `RandomReal[{0, 1}, {6,2, 2}]`.

Comment: There should be no need for `Dot[##] &` as `Dot` can be used directly.