# Why Inner doesn't work with Dot/List?

Tags: list-manipulation

[The recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120462/elementwise-dot-multiplication-for-lists-of-matrices) about generalizing `Dot` for list of matrices had a nice solution/comment using `Inner`.

Briefly, we have 6 matrices:

```
{a, b, c, x, y, z} = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}] & /@ Range[6]
```

And we want to get three matrices `{a.x, b.y, c.z}`, then possible (per comment to original question) solution would be

```
Inner[Dot, {a, b, c}, {x, y, z}, List]
```

But it fails, complaining:

> Length 2 of dimension 3 in

Why?

Comment: @Kuba, you are right... At first I wanted matrices to depend on `n`, but then forgot it.

Comment: It is too late for me to focus properly but I think that is the reason: [(9219)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9219/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Yeah... that explains it... `Inner[Dot, Unevaluated@{a, b, c}, Unevaluated@{x, y, z}, List]` works fine. Thanks! Care to post it as an answer?

Comment: Voted to mark it as a duplicate since there is nothing more to add.